# Generate comma delimited string from xml without using XSLT

Tags: .net, xml, xpath

I have a XML as listed below. I need to create a comma separated string of `AdvancedShipNotice` values. How do we do it using XPath without using XSLT?

Note: Currently I am looping throgh each node - but I am looking for a better approach

**Reference**

1. [XSLT: Generate comma-separated string from element values](http://www.geekality.net/2013/02/20/xslt-generate-comma-separated-values/)

**XML**

```
<root>
<AdvShipNotices>
    <AdvancedShipNotice>6D23513</AdvancedShipNotice>
    <StatusCD>OS</StatusCD>
    <CreatedOnDate>2014-03-28T11:08:16.750</CreatedOnDate>
    <TextilePlantCD>6D </TextilePlantCD>
</AdvShipNotices>
<AdvShipNotices>
    <AdvancedShipNotice>6D23514</AdvancedShipNotice>
    <StatusCD>OS</StatusCD>
    <CreatedOnDate>2014-03-28T11:08:16.750</CreatedOnDate>
    <TextilePlantCD>6D </TextilePlantCD>
</AdvShipNotices>
</root>
```

**VB.Net**

```
Dim objXML As New XmlDocument
Dim asnString As String
asnString = "<root>" & objASN.GetAdvShipNotices(containerScanParameter.PlantCD, containerScanParameter.UserID, , , "OS") & "</root>"
objXML.LoadXml(asnString)
```

Comment: [Any attempt](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? So we won't need to start from scratch (iterating through `AdvShipNotices` and building a string with `String.Join` and `XmlNode.InnerText`)...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Currently I am looping throgh each node - but I am looking for a better code

Comment: In XPath 2.0 you can use `string-join(/root/AdvShipNotices/AdvancedShipNotice, ',')`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
StringReader reader = new StringReader( @"
  <doc>
    <e>a</e>
    <e>b</e>
    <e>c</e>
    <e>d</e>
    <e>e</e>
  </doc>".Trim()
  ) ;

XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument() ;
xml.Load( reader ) ;

IEnumerable<string> texts = xml
                            .SelectNodes( "//*[text()]" )
                            .Cast<XmlNode>()
                            .Select( x => x.InnerText )
                            ;
string csv = String.Join( "," , texts ) ;
```

At the end of which, `csv` should hold `a,b,c,d,e`.

Depending on the structure of your XML, you might have to adjust the XPath exression to suit.

Another approach uses `XDocument`. For your sample document, something like this will work:

```
string xml =
@"<root>
    <AdvShipNotices>
      <AdvancedShipNotice>6D23513</AdvancedShipNotice>
      <StatusCD>OS</StatusCD>
      <CreatedOnDate>2014-03-28T11:08:16.750</CreatedOnDate>
      <TextilePlantCD>6D </TextilePlantCD>
    </AdvShipNotices>
    <AdvShipNotices>
      <AdvancedShipNotice>6D23514</AdvancedShipNotice>
      <StatusCD>OS</StatusCD>
      <CreatedOnDate>2014-03-28T11:08:16.750</CreatedOnDate>
      <TextilePlantCD>6D </TextilePlantCD>
    </AdvShipNotices>
  </root>" ;

XDocument doc     = XDocument.Parse( xml ) ;
string    csvFile = string.Join( Environment.NewLine ,
                      doc
                      .Root
                      .Elements()
                      .Select( e => string.Join( "," ,
                          e
                          .Elements()
                          .Select( c => c.Value )
                          )
                        )
                    ) ;
```

producing this text

```
6D23513,OS,2014-03-28T11:08:16.750,6D 
6D23514,OS,2014-03-28T11:08:16.750,6D
```